# How to define continuity of functions from $R$ to $P(R^2)$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, continuity

Consider a 2-dimensional amoeba that moves in $R^2$. This amoeba can be defined as a function $f$ from a real interval to $P(R^2)$: the real interval represents the time, and $P(R^2)$ (= the subsets of the real plane) represent the location, shape and size of the amoeba.

MY QUESTION IS: What restrictions can you put on the function $f$ to make sure that it represents a realistic movement of an amoeba, i.e., that its location and shape and size all move smoothly and without sudden jumps?

If, instead of an amoeba, there was a single point (i.e. $f$ was a function from $R$ to $R^2$), then I would just say that $f$ should be a continuous function.   But here the meaning of "continuous" is not clear because there is no natural metric on $P(R^2)$. Is there a natural way to define continuity of functions from $R$ to $P(R^2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $P(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a *way* too big set for this context. After all, the position of our amoeba has to be a rather friendly subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. In fact, the position of the amoeba may be described by its *boundary*, which has to be a simple loop, thus what you need is a continuous (or smooth, if you wish) $f:S^1\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$, such that for a fixed $t\in\mathbb{R}$, the function $f_t:S^1\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $p\mapsto f(p,t)$ is injective.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: 
* The amoeba boundary is a simple loop, so it is described as a smooth function from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.
* The movement of the amoeba over time is described as a smooth function from a real interval (the time) to the set of all such functions. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean. Note that *simple* loop means that the function $S^1\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is injective.

Comment: OK, but what if I need the internal part of the amoeba and not only its boundary? (for example, because I later want to track the change in its area, etc.)?

Comment: It doesn't matter actually. Try to look at this differently: say you want to tell me the position of the amoeba. What would be the easiest and simplest way for you to do this...? Of course, you would tell me what the boundary is. Once I know what the boundary is, I know exactly what the corresponding subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is.

Comment: And by the way, if you want to calculate the area, there is a formula that expresses it as some integral along the boundary.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not so sure that $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ is what you want; there are some really bizarre subsets of the plane. The collection of open sets seems more reasonable; you may even want them to be connected.

With that disclaimer out of the way, you may be interested in the [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

Comment: While Hausdorff distance seems to me like the way to go, it applies not to open sets but to compact sets, which seems like a reasonable assumption about an amoeba. On top of that, Hausdorff distance would even apply to a Cantor set amoeba!